# How to open my native android app from a Facebook post

Tags: android, facebook, native, deep-linking

I have an android application named Jamama. It plays sounds from my cloud. 
Its intent filter handles all URLs starting with http://jamama.com. 
When I post a Jamama URL on Facebook, and when the link is clicked from the FB app on an Android device, I'd like it to either open the app, or jump to the Google Play app to download it.
I've seen it working with many apps (Soundcloud, CandyCrush, etc). The difficulty comes from the fact that FB wraps my URL as an argument of a FB url.

Now, I've been investigating the question on the Net. 
I've seen similar questions in StackOverflow, but never really formulated as I mean, and never with a useful answer. So I'm taking my chance again here.

I did create a FB app, for which I defined the following:

- Basic Info (without  a namespace),
- App on Facebook with http[s]://jamama.com/ as URLs Native Android App, with the right package, activity, and key hashes (debug and release), and with both Facebook Login and Deep Linking enabled.

And still, clicking on the link I send in my FB post still leads to opening a page in the browser rather than opening my app.

I also heard about an API in the Facebook SDK for android to open a dedicated dialog to post a story. That could be nice, but I really need it to work with a simple text. Right now I share a text, and Android opens the right Intent chooser to give me the option to share it via Facebook, Google, mail, etc That's what I want. I don't want to make a special handling for every sharing app.

I see it working with many sites, like YouTube, SoundCloud, MuseScore, etc What am I missing so it would work for me too ?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: You just opened yourself up to a slew of "jamama jokes."

Answer (score 0):

I have a facebook app and android app which does the exact same thing almost, it sounds like you want to intercept the link/string in the browser from the click which is generated on the facebook callback side (as that is what comes first, using a basic order of operation).

To be more defined the user is on facebook (using the standard facebook app) clicks on your facebook application (maybe a banner that reads "Free Sign Up"), the callback url from your facebook application (in this case the "Free Sign Up" banner) needs to alert android threw the browser via its url/string to opens your Android app.

If the above is correct, I used a javaScript and my facebook application call back url goes to a custom html page (that uses JavaScript on a timer) which then sends a broadcast to Android and starts my app. There maybe many other ways of doing this but that is how i do it and in order to follow my path you have to start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) . The steps are as follows

1: Facebook Mobile 
2: Your Facebook Application which CLICK leads to 
3: Html/javaScript using Android webkit as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) (that interaction/CLICK)
4: Start your Android App via Intent (just like clicking on the icon in the menu)

Again, I am not the governing authority as to the many ways to do it. Hope that helps you out to some degree. If it does like my answer.

Comment: Man, how come I never saw your answer before! Something's missing in SO's notification system ? 
Anyway, sorry for ignoring it for so long. I kind of left the subject since them and moved on to other stuff, but now I feel like getting back to it. 
The links are definitely what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The updated and correct way to do this is by something called AppLinks. AppLinks was developed by Facebook in order to do exactly the thing you are describing

1. Facebook docs page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/overview
2. Official Website: http://applinks.org

So, how do you use it
(I'm describing [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) since this question is in it but it is possible in iOS)

So, in your HTML page you have to add the following

```
<head>
...
<meta property="al:android:url" content="sample://yourapp/deep_linking_uri">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.yourapp.package">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="NameOnTheStore">
...
</head>
```

In your android app you need to tie the URI you just sent to an Activity

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
   ...
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="sample" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It's <data android:scheme="sample" />, I believe, giving the way you wrote the content of your al:android:url meta property.

Comment: what do you mean by "in your HTML page" suppose you have an app which can share content, and it will be posted on your facebook wall and when I will see that post on your wall and when I will click on it it should open that app. I am not getting where to put "<head>" part?

Comment: @ReyanshMishra. You would put it in the HTML page that the post links to. All posts MUST be connected to an HTML web page. This page would then forward the person to the appropriate app. However, this answer is 3 years old so there may have been some changes in the intervening time.